# How to assign fixed row height in centimeters

Tags: vba, ms-word, row

I have Word Document with multiple tables.
I want to set row size all over document to fixed size 1cm
regardless of text size.

I can't find macros for this. I found one that deals with points not Centimeters
and also with not fixed height as I wanted.

```
Sub tablechanger()
Dim tableid As Tables
Set tableid = ActiveDocument.Tables
For Each tb In tableid
For Each rw In tb.Rows
rw.Height = 1
Next rw

Next tb

End Sub
```

Comment: Even without recourse to the CentimetersToPoints function, it's a trivial matter to supply the conversion: 1cm = (72/2.54)pt

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub tablechanger()
   Dim tableid As Tables
   Dim TB As word.Table, rw As word.Row
   Set tableid = ActiveDocument.Tables
   For Each TB In tableid
      TB.Range.rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
      For Each rw In TB.rows
        rw.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(3)
      Next rw
   Next TB
End Sub
```